# Problem for post data in ajax on wordpress plugin

Tags: ajax, wordpress, post

I am currently learning to use the wordpress CMS and I have a problem with the development of my plugin, I would need to send a data with the ajax post method, the problem is that the request is sent (status code 200, OK), but my targeted php page does not receive it .. Thank you in advance for your help =)

My code :

```
function sendSearch () {

    document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', function(){

        var search = document.getElementById('search').value;
        var dir = document.getElementById('dir').value;
        ////dir is equal to :
           <input type='hidden' id='dir' value='".plugin_dir_url(__FILE__).'filter.php'."'>                                                        
        //// 

        let xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.open("post", dir);
        xmlhttp.send(search);

        document.getElementById('search').value = "";
    })

}

sendSearch();
```

Comment: This is not how you use ajax in wordpress.  You should read https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins at least, and just search here on SO for many posts on correct use of using ajax with WP.

Comment: @HowardE  I will see that, thank you very much for your answer =)

Answer (score 0):

I tried to do as on the codex but I must have a little problem somewhere .. Same problem as above, the data is sent but never reaches its destination..
Thanks for your help =)

ajax.js :

```
function sendSearch(){
        var search = document.getElementById('search').value;
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/integrationWP/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
                method : 'POST',
                data:{
                    'action':'doAjax',
                    'value': search
                },
                success: function(data){
                    // alert('ça fonctionne !');
                },
                error: function(errorThrown){
                    alert('error');
                    console.log(errorThrown);
                }
            });
        });
    
    }

    document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', function(){
        sendSearch();
        document.getElementById('search').value = "";
    })
```

PHP file :

```
  `    add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_doAjax', 'get_data');
        add_action('wp_ajax_doAjax', 'get_data');

        function get_data(){
          if(isset($REQUEST)){
            $search = $REQUEST['value'];
            echo 'Hello';
          }
        die();
        }
```

`